# Trying to plot a velocity profile in x-y plane

Tags: plotting

I have a velocity profile for two liquids on top of each other in a pressure driven channel.
The profile is supposed to be parabolic. I plotted them up, but I can't manage to plot them in the x-y plane, it only plots with velocity on the vertical coordinate and y as the horizontal coordinate. Is there any way I can plot them in the x-y plane so that I can clearly see which liquid is ahead of the other in the channel and their parabolic profile? I am also trying to define v1 on a certain interval from y=0 to y=ha, and v2 from y=ha to y=H, so v1 and v2 are sort of piecewise.

Here is my code, this is for mercury(just to start somewhere) and water

```
v1[y_, μ1_, P_, ha_, H_, μ2_] :=
  P*(1/(2*μ1))*y*(y + ((ha^2*(μ2 - μ1) - H*μ2)/(ha*(μ2 - μ1) + H*μ1)))

v2[y_, μ1_, P_, ha_, H_, μ2_] :=
  P*(1/(2*μ2))*(y^2 + ((ha^2*(μ2 - μ1) - H*μ2)/(ha*(μ2 - μ1) + H*μ1))* y +
   (ha *  H/μ1)*( (μ1 - μ2)*(H*μ2 - ha * μ1)/(ha*(μ2 - μ1) + H*μ1 )))

Plot[{v1[y, 0.00157, -6, 1, 2, 0.001], v2[y, 0.00157, -6, 1, 2, 0.001]}, {y, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Velocity vs y]

[image: Profile]

Comment: So you need position rather than velocity - `NIntegrate`? Please note your code will be much easier to read if you didn't use Greek letters.

Comment: No time since its steady state

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "plot in the x-y plane"?  Do you need velocity to be on the horizontal axis?  Or you just need to shift the curves?  It'd be best to make a quick sketch in MS Paint and post it as illustration.  I can see that people are confused about what you mean by velocity profile.  [I believe I understand that](http://knowledgepublications.com/doe/images/DOE_Thermodynamics_Laminar_and_Turbulent_Flow_Velocity_Profiles.gif), but I also don't understand what you need exactly.

Comment: I have made a paint figure. Of course I don't need the arrows.

Comment: I guess I have to rotate my graph and somehow split V1 and V2 to two intervals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using `ParametricPlot`?

```
ParametricPlot[{{v1[y, 0.00157, -6, 1, 2, 0.001], 
   y}, {v2[y, 0.00157, -6, 1, 2, 0.001], -y}}, {y, 0, 10}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, PlotStyle -> Black, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For more precise control, you may need two separate `ParametricPlot`s and combine the output using `Show[plot1, plot2, PlotRange -> All]`.